# Why does FunctionPeriod give two different results for alternative forms of the given function?

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-function

I have a function for the variable $x>0$ and constant $a\in\mathbb{R}$. I write it in its two alternative forms

$$f(x)=\cos a\pi-\cos x\pi =-2\sin\frac{(a-x)\pi}{2}\sin\frac{(a+x)\pi}{2} $$

Then, I use  `FunctionPeriod` for both functions, for the first one, it gives $T=2$, while for the second form, it gives $T=4$. The correct one is of course $T=2$.

Why does this problem happen? How can I trust the result if the function is more complicated?

```
FunctionPeriod[       Cos[a \[Pi]]-Cos[x \[Pi]]      ,   x   ]
(* 2 *)
FunctionPeriod[        -2 Sin[(a Pi)/2-(x Pi)/2]Sin[(a Pi)/2+(x Pi)/2]  ,   x   ]
(* 4 *)
```

Comment: Note: Both might be considered correct (per the docs) but only one of them is the minimal period

Comment: I tried giving "a" some numerical values both results are 2. Once the value of "a" is cleared it gives me two different answers

Comment: @qahtah Yes, for a specific value of $a$ there is no problem.

Comment: `FunctionPeriod[-2 Sin[(a Pi)/2 - (x Pi)/2] Sin[(a Pi)/2 + (x Pi)/2] //
   Simplify, x]`

Answer (score 4):

The `FunctionPeriod` function is fragile. For example, testing
for four variants

```
With[{f = Sin[a - x] Sin[x + a]}, FunctionPeriod[#, x] & /@
 {f, f // Simplify, 2 f, 2 f // Simplify}]
```

returns `{2*Pi, 2*Pi, 2*Pi, Pi}`. Notice the wording in the
documentation "gives a period p" but **not** "gives the
minimal period p". Also, replacing the `a` with a specific nonzero
value such as `1` makes no difference, but if `a` is zero
then it gives period `Pi` in all four variants.

You wrote

> Why does this problem happen? How can I trust the result if the function is more complicated?

The problem seems to be that the undocumented code
that Mathematica uses is not capable of finding the
**minimal** period in all cases. As far as I know,
if it returns a nonzero period, then it is a genuine
period, but may not be minimal.

Answer (score 4):

Whether the documentation is being careful or vague, as I hinted in my comment and Somos pointed out, it states `FunctionPeriod` returns a number $T$ such that $f(x+T) = f(x)$.  It need not be positive and it need not be minimal.  We probably need a better test suite to meet the OP's demand for reliability, but I will suggest that `TrigToExp` greatly aids finding the minimal positive period for trigonometric expressions:

```
FunctionPeriod[TrigToExp@ f, x]
```

`FunctionPeriod` tends to return a negative value after `TrigToExp`, so we need to change its sign if a positive value is required.
[***Deleted:*** `FunctionPeriod` over the complexes....It caused more trouble than it was worth, no matter how cute it was.]

```
negateIfNeg = If[Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ[#], -#, #] &;

Block[{f = {
    Style["Somos", Bold, Italic],
     Sin[a - x] Sin[x + a],
     2 Sin[a - x] Sin[x + a] // Simplify,
    Style["OP", Bold, Italic],
     Cos[a Pi] - Cos[x Pi],
     -2 Sin[(a Pi)/2 - (x Pi)/2] Sin[(a Pi)/2 + (x Pi)/2],
     -2 Sin[(a Pi)/2 - (x Pi)/2] Sin[(a Pi)/2 + (x Pi)/2] // 
      TrigExpand,
    Style["M-E2", Bold, Italic], Sin[4 a x] + Sin[2 a x],
     Cos[a x] Cos[a b x] Cos[a b c x],
     Cos[2 x] Cos[3 x] Cos[5 x]},
   $Assumptions = {b, c} \[Element] Integers},
  {#,
   FunctionPeriod[#, x],
   negateIfNeg@FunctionPeriod[TrigToExp@#, x]
   } & /@ f //
     Prepend[#, 
       Style[#, Bold, Larger] & /@ {"Input", "FP", "T2Exp"}] & //
     # /. {
         {in_Style, 0, 0} :> {in},
         {in_, fp : Except[_Style], t2e_} /; fp =!= t2e :> {in, 
           Style[fp, Red], t2e}} & //
     Grid
  ] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

[*Update:*
The trouble with the deleted `Complexes` solution suggests that a broader test suite is needed to determine whether the reliability the OP seeks is achieved. `FunctionPeriod` is sensitive to the form of the expression, and I have no way of proving `TrigToExp` works robustly. In fact, if you `Expand` it on the `...Cos[a b c x]` example above, `FunctionPeriod` fails to mind the minimal period. One might need to find the `FunctionPeriod` on several forms and their `PolynomialGCD`. ]